# Change backgroundColor of a view repeatedly and with animation

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I am planning to do an app which has a continuous change of colors in the background. In my idea, there should be an UIView animation after the other one that should repeat itself again and again. This my attempt

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[UIView animateWithDuration:4 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse  animations:^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        NSLog(@"1");
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            NSLog(@"2");
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                NSLog(@"3");
            } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
                    NSLog(@"4");
                } completion:NULL];
            }];
        }];
    }];


} completion:NULL];
```

However this doesn't only look messy, but also doesn't repeat itself. Any advice?

Comment: you should use CAKeyframeAnimation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an array of colours and a `currentColorIndex` property. Something which gives you the list of colours and a current position in the list. Now have a single method with a single `animateWithDuration:` in it. In that method, get the next colour and then update the index (wrapping back to 0 when it gets to the end) and run the animation. In the animation `completion` block, call the method again.

Comment: isnt this infinite recursion and calling the method in itself will increase the stack frame massively and memory will be all taken after 30 mins?

Comment: It won't increase the stack depth infinitely because the completion is called asynchronously after the animation is complete. You probably want to add some way to abort the recursion instead of starting the next iteration though.